# SELECT/LOCATE Query Outputting Incorrect Results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column (kills) with values separated by colons as such: `0;2;0`. I wanted to select whatever the middle digit may be, and came up with this query:

```
SELECT RIGHT(kills, LOCATE(';', kills) - 1)-LEFT(kills, LOCATE(';', kills) - 1) FROM stats WHERE id='135' AND LOCATE(';', kills) > 0;
```

(I'm aware the where clause is specific, it was for debug purposes. It would realistically be set to a variable which outputs the row id)

It works perfectly fine when the results all have the same decimal place such as `1;2;3` or `10;20;30`, but returns wild results when the case is otherwise, such as `1;20;30` or `10;20;3`.

`1;20;21` outputs `0`. -- `10;20;2` outputs `-10`.

`2;20;21` outputs `-1`. -- `20;20;2` outputs `-20`.

`9;20;21` outputs `-8`. -- `90;20;2` outputs `-90`.

I would like to select the middle value of all of these values even if one value doesn't share the same decimal place.

Comment: There is no PHP in this question. Please avoid using irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the middle number of three, then you want the second number.  Use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(kills, ';', 2), ';', -1)
```